# Backgrid doesn't render the grid with the updated collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backgrid

I'm using Backgrid and I create the Backgrid Object as follows in my Controller:

```
  $.when(recipeRequest).done(function (recipes) {
     List.grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
      columns: columns, // where columns is defined elsewhere
      collection: recipes // recipes is the result of a fetch
    })

  // Then add it to the Marionette template
}
```

The above works perfectly and items display as expected

Once the table is displayed we are providing filtering functionality ServerSide as follows:

```
  filterRecipes: function (query) {
  // remove any incomplete network requests
    _.each(RecipeManager.fetchXhrs, function (r) {
        r.abort()
     })
  // get a filtered set of recipes
  var filteredRecipes = RecipeManager.request('recipe:entities', query)
  $.when(filteredRecipes).done(function (recipes) {

     // this line shows that the result set is being updated as expected with for example 6 results
    console.log(recipes)

    // setting the new recipe result set to the grid.collection 
    List.grid.collection = recipes 

    // here the table rerenders but there are a LOT more results on the table - not 6 as expected
    List.grid.render()  
  })
}
```

I'm expecting the table to be repopulated with the new collection once the results are returned but my table still shows all the old records.

I'm following the example written here [How would I refresh a Backgrid table with new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912685/how-would-i-refresh-a-backgrid-table-with-new-data)  So it should redraw the table once the collection has been reset?  Or do I need to empty the table first?  Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [backgridjs](http://backgridjs.com/)

> Fully reactive. Relevant parts of the grid re-renders automatically upon data changes.

I have not gone through annotated source code but am guessing rerendering is tied to `collection` events. So, you do not need to explicitly call the `render` method.

```
 $.when(filteredRecipes).done(function (recipes) {

     // this line shows that the result set is being updated as expected with for example 6 results
     console.log(recipes)

     // setting the new recipe result set to the grid.collection 
     // considering recipes is backbone collection
     // if result is array of objects then List.grid.collection.reset(recipes)
     // it should re render the grid 
     List.grid.collection.reset(recipes.models); 
 })
```